# Ranking based on multiple conditions

Tags: r

I have a dataset (nm) as shown below, where first three columns shows user is using that product or not i.e. 1(yes) or 0(not). The next three columns shows what is the percentage of liking that products where A_TT corresponds to A_TT_1.1 and likewise:

```
nm

A_TT  B_TT  C_TT  A_TT_1.1  B_TT_2.1  C_TT_3.1
0      0     1     0.06     0.84       0.89
1      1     0     0.92     0.83       0.94
0      1     0     0.09     0.9        0.13
1      0     1     0.87     0.05       0.9
0      0     0     0.13     0.11       0.14
```

I want to add two columns in dataset(nm) i.e. Rank1 & Rank2, which ranks top two percentages having following two conditions:

a) Select and rank only where value is "zero" in first three columns
b) In rank column it should return its column name.

The final output should be:

```
nm

A_TT    B_TT    C_TT    A_TT_1.1    B_TT_2.1    C_TT_3.1   Rank 1   Rank 2
0         0      1       0.06        0.84       0.89      B_TT_2.1  A_TT_1.1
1         1      0       0.92        0.83       0.94      C_TT_3.1  NONE
0         1      0       0.09        0.9        0.13      C_TT_3.1  A_TT_1.1
1         0      1       0.87        0.05       0.9       B_TT_2.1  NONE
0         0      0       0.13        0.11       0.14      C_TT_3.1  A_TT_1.1
```

I have tried many options but nothing works. Thanks in advance for providing solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do this with `apply` specifying `MARGIN = 1` to loop over the rows

```
nm[paste0("Rank", 1:2)] <-  t(apply(nm, 1, FUN = function(x)  {
                         i1 <- !x[1:3] #logical index giving TRUE for 0
                         x1 <- x[4:6][i1] #subset elements 4:6 based on i1
                         names(x1[order(-x1)])[1:2] #order the 'x1', extract names
                          }))
nm
#  A_TT B_TT C_TT A_TT_1.1 B_TT_2.1 C_TT_3.1    Rank1    Rank2
#1    0    0    1     0.06     0.84     0.89 B_TT_2.1 A_TT_1.1
#2    1    1    0     0.92     0.83     0.94 C_TT_3.1     <NA>
#3    0    1    0     0.09     0.90     0.13 C_TT_3.1 A_TT_1.1
#4    1    0    1     0.87     0.05     0.90 B_TT_2.1     <NA>
#5    0    0    0     0.13     0.11     0.14 C_TT_3.1 A_TT_1.1
```

NOTE: Instead of "NONE", it is better to have `NA` as missing value as it is easier to remove those values with functions `is.na/complete.cases/na.rm/na.omit` etc.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another attempt:

```
x <- df[,1:3]
y <- df[,4:6]
y[x==1] <- NA
z <- t(apply(y,1,function(x) colnames(y)[order(x, decreasing = T, na.last = T)]))[,1:2]
z[rowSums(!x)==1, 2] <- NA
df[,c("Rank1","Rank2")] <- z

 # A_TT B_TT C_TT A_TT_1.1 B_TT_2.1 C_TT_3.1    Rank1    Rank2
# 1    0    0    1     0.06     0.84     0.89 B_TT_2.1 A_TT_1.1
# 2    1    1    0     0.92     0.83     0.94 C_TT_3.1     <NA>
# 3    0    1    0     0.09     0.90     0.13 C_TT_3.1 A_TT_1.1
# 4    1    0    1     0.87     0.05     0.90 B_TT_2.1     <NA>
# 5    0    0    0     0.13     0.11     0.14 C_TT_3.1 A_TT_1.1
```